# jQuery clone() and 302 image sources -- how to avoid reloading in Firefox?

Tags: jquery, clone, http-status-code-302

I have a group of images within a `<div>`. All these images are served through a 302 instead of a 200 for security purposes (servlet serving image based on authentication).

I would like to clone that `<div>` and append it to another container.

When doing so in all browsers except Firefox, the images are not reloaded. It appears those browsers understand it's the same image.

In Firefox, each image is reloaded after the clone/append. I'd like to avoid that. Does anyone have any recommendations on how?

UPDATED with code example:

```
<div>
    <p><button type="button" id="btn1">Clone 1</button> <button type="button" id="btn2">Clone 2</button></p>
</div>

<div id="group1">
    <div id="imgs">
        <p><img src="https://example.com/image/9c90434ed657427dad29"></p>
        <p><img src="https://example.com/image/977b5dfe5e064880b164"></p>
        <p><img src="https://example.com/image/8f22d7fd2a2343ab99c9"></p>
        <p><img src="https://example.com/image/898c022e20b742c88ae6"></p>
        <p><img src="https://example.com/image/8319fe1d23064b5d8011"></p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="group2"></div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            $("#imgs").clone().appendTo("#group1");
        });
        $("#btn2").click(function(){
            $("#imgs").clone().appendTo("#group2");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sure. I edited my original post with a code example. The key is that in Firefox, when you clone the `div#imgs` and append the images all reload. In all other browsers, they don't. Also important to note that all those images are being served as a 302 redirect for authentication purposes (it's an enterprise app with privacy on assets). My goal is to see if there is a jQuery work around before we look an alternative to the 302. Thanks.

Comment: Also worth noting: if you change the clone() to detach(), the images don't reload in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding prefetch tags for Firefox users. I believe FF still supports the prefetch relationship; they did come up with it.

```
<link rel="prefetch" src="https://example.com/image/9c90434ed657427dad29">
<link rel="prefetch" src="https://example.com/image/977b5dfe5e064880b164">
<link rel="prefetch" src="https://example.com/image/8f22d7fd2a2343ab99c9">
<link rel="prefetch" src="https://example.com/image/898c022e20b742c88ae6">
<link rel="prefetch" src="https://example.com/image/8319fe1d23064b5d8011">
```