# IFrame and others Reloading after Clone and Append

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written below JavaScript using JQuery. I have tested it in Firebug and it is working.

What I am doing here?
I am copying social share bar and putting (after clone) in fixed position near to Post body. I think if someone share something then it will work as everything is same.

My question is about optimization. 
1) I see every iframe esp. Facebook is reloading again after clone and append. I wish to avoid that.

```
function copySocial() {

jQuery('<div/>', {
    id: 'dsocial',
    left: '25px',
    position: 'fixed',
    top: '400px',
    width: '44px',
    display: 'relative'
}).appendTo('#container');

var social = jQuery('div.share.social').clone(true).appendTo('#dsocial').css({"left":"25px", "position":"fixed", "top":"400px", "width":"45px"});

}

if ((jQuery(window).width() > 1025) && (jQuery(document).width() > 1025)) {
    window.setTimeout(copySocial, 20000);
}
```

2nd problem is - 
 I have to apply CSS two times. First at new DIV creation time and 2nd at the time of append. Why it is required. I tried to remove CSS (position etc) at the time of DIV creation but it did not work.

Comment: If you wish to play or need to experiment with the code before replying on it then point your browser to any Post/Article at http://www.satya-weblog.com/ and use Firebug. Thanks!

Comment: I got the post little similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590106/jquery-clone-and-302-image-sources-how-to-avoid-reloading-in-firefox but answer is not accepted there and I do not know how to use that trick.